# Calculate the degree of polymerisation. It's molecular weight and its repeat structure are given

Tags: polymers

I understand how to calculate the degree of polymerisation normally, but in this question, the extra H and OH outside the bracketed monomer have thrown me off. Do I include their atomic masses in the overall Atomic mass for the degree of polymerisation or are they not part of the monomer chain and so not part of the calculation?

[image: Repeat Structure Diagram]

Comment: It's not like can have no terminal groups (unless oligomer is cyclic)

Comment: The degree of polymerisation is $n$. The *molar* mass of the molecule of course includes the end grous. You need to use the correct terms to not get confused!